# How to set a default value on a form when it's excluded?

Tags: django

I've tried 3 different approaches, and nothing seems to work. Here's my view:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DealershipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dealership = form.save(commit=False)
            dealership.entered_by = User(id=2)
            dealership.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Dealership added.')
    else:
        form = DealershipForm()
    return response(request, template='misc/my_template.html',
                    vars={'form':form})
```

I've also tried modifying the `cleaned_data` just after `form.is_valid`, I've tried setting `initial`, and `instance`, nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DealershipForm(request.POST, instance=Dealership(my_field="my_value"))
```

Should work.

**EDIT:**

Your code after modification:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DealershipForm(request.POST, instance=Dealership(entred_by=User(id=2))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Dealership added.')
    else:
        form = DealershipForm()
    return response(request, template='misc/my_template.html',
                    vars={'form':form})
```

**Edit after your comment:**

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = Dealership()
        instance.entered_by_id = 2
        form = DealershipForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Dealership added.')
    else:
        form = DealershipForm()
    return response(request, template='misc/my_template.html',
                    vars={'form':form})
```

Comment: If I do `DealershipForm(request.POST, instance=Dealership(entered_by=User.objects.get(id=2)))` then it works, but then I'm hitting the DB to look up the user object, no? Why should I need to do that when I'm just saving the ID?